# Reinstall ubuntu without usb or wifi

Tags: reinstall

I am trying to reinstall ubuntu, but I cant download a fresh image because I don't have any wifi (I'm on my phone right now). Is there a way to re-install ubuntu using an existing installation? I haven't found any information so far relating to my issue

Comment: What do you mean using `an existing installation`?

Comment: I am currently running ubuntu but I want a fresh install

Comment: SO how was it installed?

Comment: I installed it a long time ago when I had access to wifi

Comment: Why are you trying to reinstall?

Comment: OK, in that case AFAIK it's not possible.

Comment: Fully "reinstalling" is not possible in this scenario. If you are reinstalling, you are probably trying to solve a problem though - what problem is that?

Comment: The wifi won't connect and none of the solutions iv found online have helped.

Comment: If you can tether through your phone, this may help with your wifi situation, and you could continue on from there.. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taikedz/wifi-script/master/bin/wifi